# Input component for uploading regular files?

Tags: admin-on-rest

There doesn't seem to be an input component for uploading files and I can't manage to edit the existing ImageInput to work either. If anyone has any examples of how to upload non-image files I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I managed to come up with a bit of a workaround. I'm sure there has to be an easier way but this is what worked for my individual case.

I had been using the `simpleRestClient` whose `convertRESTRequestToHTTP` function returns the `url` and `options` variables which are later passed to `fetch`. For `CREATE` cases, it sets them to the following

```
url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
options.method = 'POST';
options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
```

So it was sending a string as the request body instead of the `FormData` that my backend was expecting. I had to create a new `FormData` object and append all the items from `params.data`. I then attached this form to `options.body`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean uploading to a web server?  Try using an `input` tag with the `type` attribute set to "file".

```
<input type="file" name=  etc>
```